# Mesh objects and a draw function

Tags: c++, directx11, objects, mesh

I'm currently working with a mesh class so I can easily create mesh objects. Now I want a draw function in my mesh class so when ever i want draw it to the screen I can just call it without any fuss. But i have run in to a dilema and i need some insperation/ other persons perspectiv. To draw a mesh object there is alot of thing you need. You need blend states, rasterizer state, depth stencils ect (lets call them "tools" for futher reference).

Now there is a couple of diffrent ways you can go about it and i wanted your input to choose one.

1. You can have the object create their own tools. It requires more space, but you dont have to pass pointer around as much.
2. You create the tools in the GameEngine object and pass pointers to the tools in the draw function parameters. It looks messy and could cost alot of time, but it take up less space.
3. You create the tools in the GameEngine object and then store pointers to them in the mesh object. Now this save both time and space, however i got the feeling that this could get really messy and caus you alot of trouble easily.

I greatly appriceate any feedback or diffrent solutions. Thank in advance.

Comment: You can also specify states in effects (.fx files).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205052(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ooh i didnt know that

Comment: Normally these states are part of the material or part of the render pass and are not called "tools."  Using the common vernacular might help you find better documentation when searching.

Comment: To amplify a bit on what Sean said: you usually have multiple meshes using the same material, and perhaps multiple materials using the same shader code with different textures etc.  The render states don't belong to the object but rather to the shader, and the object would have a pointer to the material it uses, which would in turn have a pointer to its shader.  See [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/different-shaders-for-different-objects-directx-11/49833) for more details.

Comment: Sorry didnt have any better word for them. But if i get you rigth, your saying that rather then set each object with shaders ect. I should prepare diffrent sections of my code. Like one section where i draw transparant object, one for non transparant ect ?

Comment: It feels like code like that isnt very dynamic ( tho maby faster)

Comment: @FredrikBostonWestman You can certainly make a shader/material system that's partially or completely data-driven (I think that's what you mean by "dynamic").  It's a lot of work, though.  Keeping some things hard-coded can make development simpler and faster.  You can add data-drivenness a little at a time as you need to.

Comment: dynamic system = a system that is easy to change and implement new functions ( atleast that is how I learned it). But thanks:) that question you linked gave me the insperation i needed :) gonna make like a hierarchy of objects. First a shader object that contains the shader . Inside of that is also a array of material object which contains the settings for each matterials. And inside of the material object there is an array of mech obj, and inside the mech an array of instances of that mech. That way you can go true all of them very fast and makes the system very dynamic :)

Comment: @NathanReed i saw you where the one that wrote that anwser on the other question, its a good system, but what if one mesh have several materials?

Comment: @FredrikBostonWestman It has to be split into several meshes, one for each material. I think of a "mesh" as being a chunk of triangles you can draw in one call, so it all has the same shader/material.  An object may be made of multiple meshes if it has multiple materials, or independently moving parts (e.g. a car and its wheels), etc.

Comment: makes sence, i only working with .obj file rigth now and they dont have animations, so i never tougth about it that way :) guess i have to rework the code abit to split i up to diffrent meshes

Comment: @FredrikBostonWestman: A hierarchy for shaders is a little backwards.  Materials have shaders, not the other way around.  A single material might need different shaders for different passes, e.g. for forward vs deferred lighting or the like.  Keep a list of objects; for each object, add each mesh to a queue.  Sort the queue so meshes with identical materials or shaders are adjacent and so transparent objects are drawn after opaque ones and depth sorted.  Then iterate over the sorted queue and draw, only changing state if the current mesh's material is different than the previous.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch seems like a good idea, well have to think about this a bit, but what do you meen with depth sorted ?

Comment: Draw objects in order of distance from the camera.  For standard transparency, you _must_ use the painter's algorithm (draw the farther objects before closer objects).  Even for opaque objects with Z-buffering you can obtain on some hardware performance improvements by using reverse-painter's algorithm (closest first) so that the Z-buffer stops the fragment shader from drawing occluded objects (depends on hardare, scene/shader complexity, etc.)

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch do you really have to use the painters algorithm for tranceparancy. Cant you just use a z buffer, draw the object in whatever order they come, then last draw all transparant objects ? Even if you used the painter algorithm, how could you possibly sort all objects in the correct order if they need diffrent shaders and stuff. Say the furthest object needs shader 1, the second furthest need shader 3, and the 3rd need shader 2. Would take alot of time change back and forth all the time.

Comment: nvm, this is getting to long, i making a question out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Direct3D 11. So the *only* thing your mesh should be doing is setting up the Input Assembly stage and issuing some form of Draw call. So your mesh should only call `IASetIndexBuffer`, `IASetInputLayout`, `IASetPrimitiveTopology`, and `IASetVertexBuffers`, followed by one or more `Draw*` calls.

Everything else should be handled by whatever code *called* the mesh's draw function. A mesh is just a dumb collection of the vertex state needed to draw. Any higher-level logic (what shaders to use, blend modes, etc) should be handled *outside* of the mesh.